# How to install GNS3 on Linux Mint?

Tags: linux-mint

I want to install GNS3 on my Linux Mint. The website gave me two files to download

```
GNS3-0.8.3-src.tar.gz
GNS3-0.8.3-src.tar.bz2
```

I downloaded them both but I don't know the difference and I have never installed anything on Linux Mint.

Answer (score 1):

These are just different ways of compressing the file.  The contents will be the same so you should just be able to use `tar` to extract the contents of either one.

So something like the following:

```
tar -xzvf GNS3-0.8.3-src.tar.gz
```

My guess is that there will be a README in the uncompressed code that will give you instructions.

Comment: I corrected your answer. `tar` does not take an extraction location as an argument. To specify where you want the files extracted to, e.g. `foo/`, use `tar -xvf GNS3-0.8.3-src.tar.gz -C foo/`.

Answer (score 1):

**Instructions for installing the latest GNS3 from source on Ubuntu distributions.**

GNS3 is a graphical network simulator. In order to emulate Cisco network devices, the `dynamips` emulator will need to be installed as well.

1. Install the following recommended packages:

   `sudo apt-get install qt4-dev-tools`

   `sudo apt-get install pyqt4-dev-tools`
2. Before downloading the files for GNS, create the following two
   directories:

   `sudo mkdir /opt/GNS3`

   `sudo mkdir /opt/GNS3/Dynamips`
3. Go to the [GNS download page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gns-3/files/GNS3/)
   for the latest version (The latest version is 0.8.4-RC2) or download directly from [here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gns-3/files/GNS3/0.8.4-RC2/GNS3-0.8.4-RC2-src.tar.bz2/download).
4. Go to the [dynamips download page](https://sourceforge.net/projects/gns-3/files/Dynamips/):

   - Select the latest version (currently 0.2.8-RC3-community) depending upon your machine architecture.
   - [64-bit version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gns-3/files/Dynamips/0.2.8-RC3-community/dynamips-0.2.8-RC3-community-x86_64.bin/download)
   - [32-bit version](http://sourceforge.net/projects/gns-3/files/Dynamips/0.2.8-RC3-community/dynamips-0.2.8-RC3-community-x86.bin/download)
5. Go to the folder where you downloaded the two files.

   - Unpack the GNS files:
   - `sudo tar -jxf GNS3-0.8.4-RC2-src.tar.bz2`
   - Move the files to the `/opt/GNS3` directory:

     - `sudo mv GNS3-0.8.2-src/* /opt/GNS3`
   - Move the dynamips binary to the `/opt/GNS3/Dynamips` directory:

     - `sudo mv dynamips-0.2.8-RC2-x86.bin /opt/GNS3/Dynamips`
   - Change the permissions on the Dynamips binary to make it executable:

     - `sudo chmod +x /opt/GNS3/Dynamips/dynamips-0.2.8-RC2-x86.bin`
6. Start GNS3

   - `sudo python gns3`

I would recommend taking a look at the following video from the GNS3 team for further instructions and decent explanation of validating the rest of your GNS3 installation.

[GNS3 installation tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=4CuMn9x96x8).

[Source](https://askubuntu.com/questions/256123/how-do-i-install-the-new-gns3-release/256743#256743)

Answer (score 0):

Although jmreicha's solution will work if you want to install from source, the easiest way to install most programs on any Debian derived system (including Ubuntu and Linux Mint) is to use `apt-get`. For example, this command will install GNS3:

```
$ sudo  apt-get install gns3
```

For a graphical way, try `Synaptic Package Manager` or `Software Manager` from the Menu->Administration.